# Nginx: Can't open error.log, cannot load certificate [how to fix permissions?]

Tags: nginx, permissions, lets-encrypt

So I have a homeserver running nginx which is serving a Nextcloud instance. The Nextcloud instance is working beautifully, but I'm getting nginx self-reported errors like such when executing

> nginx -t

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020/02/27 15:50:55 [warn] 6985#6985: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2020/02/27 15:50:55 [emerg] 6985#6985: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

not quite sure what to do about that - my google-fu is failing me for now. It seems it might have something to do with getting permissions set right, but *ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com* outputs

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root ssl-cert  36 Jan 21 08:38 cert.pem -> ../../archive/myserver.com/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root ssl-cert  37 Jan 21 08:38 chain.pem -> ../../archive/myserver.com/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root ssl-cert  41 Jan 21 08:38 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/myserver.com/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root ssl-cert  39 Jan 21 08:38 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/myserver.com/privkey1.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root ssl-cert 692 Jan 21 08:38 README
```

*ls -l -R /var/log/nginx* doesn't do anything, but executing it as sudo yields:

```
-rwxrw-rw- 1 www-data www-data    6553 Feb 27 15:19 access.log
```

for every entry. Does that seem alright?

EDIT: @RichardSmith is the man, his comment below pointing out to run *nginx -t* as sudo did the trick. I feel slightly stupid now, so thanks man ;). *sudo nginx -T* now also works, allowing me to further troubleshoot another problem.

Comment: `sudo chown -R www-data ../../archive/myserver.com/`

Comment: Are you running `nginx -t` as `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

@RichardSmith's comment suggested running `nginx -t` as `sudo`, which did the trick.

`sudo nginx -T` now also works, allowing me to further troubleshoot another problem.